# Python script not working on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: python

I am making a Telegram bot with parsing in Python Aiogram with PostgreSQL database. Everything works on my local computer, but when I upload the script to the Ubuntu 20.04 server using docker-compose, the script stops working, although it does not give an error. Here's an example:

```
    print(1)
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=COUNT_OF_PROCESSES) as pool_executor:
        print(2)
        db_datas = [[skins, stickers, proxies_list] for skins in skins_arrays]
        print(3)
        results = [pool_executor.submit(wrapper, db_data) for db_data in db_datas]
        print(4)
        concurrent.futures.wait(results, return_when=concurrent.futures.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        print(5)
        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            f_success = f.result()
            for _ in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                pool_executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)
            print(f_success)
```

On the local computer, the console displays:

```
1
2
3
4
```

And the bot works, the result of the parsing is posted in the Telegram chat, some information is displayed in the console. And on the server:

```
1
2
3
```

and after that the code is idle, after a while it gives an error:

```
/src/handlers.py:229: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited
    break
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

and after that nothing happens. As if the line
`results = [pool_executor.submit (wrapper, db_data) for db_data in db_datas]` gives an error, but the script continues to run. This is my first experience of uploading code to the server, I will be grateful for your help!

**UPD.**
I tried to start the bot in one process without using the concurrent.futures module, but then nothing was output to the console. So hardly a problem with this module.

**UPD.2**
I have recreated the question with a more precise topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68882377/the-python-script-freezes-and-does-nothing).

Comment: did you make sure they both have the same python and library versions?

Comment: You should try viewing the logs for the image (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) and ssh'ing into the docker image and executing the script manually to see if it gives any errors. I suspect that there might be issues with being able to connect to the DB from the Docker image.

Comment: @drum I don't know how to check installed Python packages in docker, but in requirements.txt I specified the same versions as on the local computer. I would be grateful if you could tell how it can be viewed!

Comment: @AndrewWei I can already see the logs of the bot container, there is nothing unusual there, and the line is repeated in the database container: `2021-08-21 14:09:02.045 UTC [1702] FATAL:  terminating connection due to unexpected postmaster exit`

Comment: You should try looking at your PostgreSQL logs as well if you can and see if the requests are getting through or if there were errors.

Comment: @AndrewWei Can you tell me how to look at them? When I write `sudo docker logs -f steamtrader`, I only see the logs that are shown when the bot starts and the line that I indicated above. I went to the folder where PostgreSQL is installed and cannot find the logs here.

Comment: You should be able to execute a `SHOW log_directory;` to get the log directory.

Comment: @AndrewWei when I try to log into the psql of the PostgreSQL user I get the error: `Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236262/discussion-between-andrew-wei-and-iiiyth1k).